# PHPExcel how to zip

Tags: download, zip, phpexcel, php-ziparchive

I can't find any example that will show how to zip my xlsx file. Idea is that i want to create few xlsx files and then zip it and force that archive to get downloaded. If some could write an example. Best would be if xlsx or zip files wouldnt stay at server disc. Would be great if it would be on fly creating files->zipping->download.

To save 1 xlsx file im doing this:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="User&Host_'.date('d-m-Y').'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: You each xlsx file to your server in turn, then Add to your zip from there using the standard PHP ziparchive library [addfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) method; then you can delete the xlsx file from the server and direct the zip to the browser once you've added them all. As an alternative, use output buffering to get the xlsx filestreams as PHP variables; then use ziparchive's [addfromstring()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php) method